# ng build can't find index.ts which exists

Tags: angular

I installed [ngx-embed-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-embed-video) as told on the documentation and it works with ng serve.

The problem, when I try to build the project, I encounter the following error. Error says index.ts doesn't exists but it exists.

```
/my-workpath/node_modules/ngx-embed-video/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

I also removed node_modules and npm build again. It's still the same.

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.7
Node: 10.10.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.10
```

What's your suggestion? 
Thank you.

Comment: Well, it might exist in your filesystem. But did adding the file to files' or 'include' in your tsconfig changed anything? e.g. a different error message?

Comment: you're going to need to post your tsconfig.jsons, your import path for the module, and possibly either your webpack config or angular-cli.json